# Dealing with OPNET Simulation dropped packets

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how do i deal with this warning? using opnet modeller 14.5
WARNING(S):
The IP packet (ID 67635, Tree 44714) is being
dropped because its TTL field decrements
to zero.
Interface Received: 192.0.3.1
Packet Destination: 192.0.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Guess you are using some already-made models by OPNET? For an IP packet, when it passes an router/hop, the TTL (time-to-live) field is decremented by 1. When TTL becomes 0, it will be dropped by routers. TTL is something that the sender of the packet sets (e.g. `traceroute -m 20` sets TTL of each ping packet from 1 up to 20) to the packet. So if you don't want your packet to be dropped on the way, manually set the TTL to some larger values, or configure your model to do so.